# Can a for loop with if be made to work like an if with elif and else branches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, if-statement

I have a code like:

```
if 'x' in longstr:
    longstr = longstr.replace('x', '')
elif 'y' in longstr:
    longstr = longstr.replace('y', '')
elif 'z' in longstr:
    longstr = longstr.replace('z', '')
else:
    longstr = longstr.replace('foo', '')
```

If I wanted to use a `for` loop instead:

```
for char in ['x','y','z']:
    if char in longstr:
        longstr = longstr.replace(str, '')
        break
```

How can I replace the `else:` final / general case in the `if..elif..else` example above (`else: longstr = longstr.replace('xyz', '')`)?

And above all, which one of the two forms performs better?

Comment: That `else` case will never have any effect; if `longstr` contains 'xyz', then you would have taken the 'x' path (and not removed any y or z). Also, read what Martijn said about storing the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an `else:` suite to the `for` loop:

```
for char in ['x','y','z']:
    if char in longstr:
       longstr = longstr.replace(char, '')
       break
else:
    longstr = longstr.replace('xyz', '')
```

The `else` suite in a `for` loop is only executed if the `for` loop ended without ending early with `break`. See the [`for` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> When the items are exhausted *[...]*, the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.
>
> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

To see which one performs better, you'd have to time them using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). However, unless you are executing a *critical code section in a tight loop*, please stick with `if...elif...else` as the `for...else` combo is not well known and will leave many programmers not aware of the semantics scratching their head. Moreover, for your toy example, you'd use regular expressions over a `if` test or `for` loop anyway.

Timing these two trivial examples:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> def example1(longstr):
...     if 'x' in longstr:
...         longstr = longstr.replace('x', '')
...     elif 'y' in longstr:
...         longstr = longstr.replace('y', '')
...     elif 'z' in longstr:
...         longstr = longstr.replace('z', '')
...     else:
...         longstr = longstr.replace('foo', '')
...
>>> def example2(longstr):
...     for char in ['x','y','z']:
...         if char in longstr:
...            longstr = longstr.replace(char, '')
...            break
...     else:
...         longstr = longstr.replace('xyz', '')
...
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> from random import choice
>>> teststring = ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)])
>>> for ex in (example1, example2):
...     count, total = Timer('ex(s)', 'from __main__ import teststring as s, ex').autorange()
...     print(f'{ex.__name__}: {total/count * 1000000}µs')
...
example1: 15.999997949984389µs
example2: 16.788980951241683µs
```

shows that there is just 1.8 **microsecond** between them. If I re-run the samples a few times, one or the other example wins by similar extremely small margins. That doesn't really make one or the other fastest, so you can consider them equal **in this case**.

However, if you do have a need to micro-optimise such a section, you need to do your own timings.